# How does a linear map behave on related line segments?

Tags: geometry

Let $f\colon \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be
given by $f(x,y)=ax+by$.

Let $AB$ be a line segement which bisects another line segment $CD$.

Suppose that
$$f(A)= 5\qquad
f(B)=5$$
If $f(C)= 10$,
what is $f(D)$?

Comment: Some periods, commas and some spacing would also help to make this clearer...and, of course, using LaTeX for mathematics. I also can't understand how a segment $\;AB\;$ can bisect a segment $\,BC\;$ ...same $\;B\;$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g:=A\vee B$ be the line containing the points $A$ and $B$. Since $f$ is linear we have $f\bigl((1-t)A+tB\bigr)=(1-t)f(A)+tf(B)=5$ for all $t\in{\mathbb R}$; in other words: The function $f$ is $\equiv5$ on  $g$. In particular, $f(M)=5$, where $M$ is the midpoint of $CD$. In a similar way we have
$$5=f(M)={1\over2}\bigl(f(C)+f(D)\bigr)\ .$$
Together with $f(C)=10$ this implies $f(D)=0$.

Note that the above argument holds even if $f$ were given as $f(x,y)=ax+by+c$.

Comment: can you give some comments on why F is constant on g?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough information to answer the question. Let $a=1$ and $b=0$, so $f(x)=x$.

Let $A=(5,0)$, $B=(5,2)$, and $C=(10,10)$.

Then $D$ could be any point on an open ray from $C$ through the midpoint of $AB$, but these points all give different values for $f$.